# Is there a way to determine locks that a given query might apply on SQL objects?

Tags: sql-server, locking

Consider a simple query, as simple as a select statement:

```
select * from Teachers where Name like N'%John%'
```

As soon as I start this query, it finishes. Thus, I get no chance to see sp_who2 to find out what type of lock this query has applied on database objects.

I can inflate this query with transaction statements:

```
begin transaction

select * from Teachers where Name like N'%John%'

-- Here, I won't commit transaction, thus holding the lock
```

But frankly, that doesn't seem the proper way for natural locking detection, because I've manipulated the default behavior using transaction statements.

Do we have a tool, like Display Estimated Execution Plan to show us some information about locking of a given query? If not, how can we find out what type of lock a given query can apply on a database, because they get executed TOO fast to be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot determine the lock beforehand that a query may apply.

You can check [Different techniques to identify blocking in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2732/different-techniques-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/)

> In order to resolve a blocked process, we first need to determine
>   which process is the blocking process and then if possible kill the
>   blocking process. There are many different ways in SQL Server to
>   identify a blocks and blocking process that are listed as follow:
>
> - Activity Monitor
> - SQLServer:Locks Performance Object
> - DMVs
>
>   - sys.dm_exec_requests
>   - sys.dm_tran_locks
>   - sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
> - SQL Server Profiler Locks Event Category